# Splitting of a topological vector space (TVS) into an (a) countable sum and (b) direct integral of subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

TVS = topological vector space. Any subspace of a TVS is a TVS in the induced-topology sense.

DEFINITION

For TVS spaces ${\mathbb{V}}_1\subset\mathbb V$, a TVS subspace ${\mathbb{V}}_2\subset\mathbb V$ is a *topological complement* of ${\mathbb{V}}_1$ in $\mathbb V$, if $\mathbb V$ is their direct sum both algebraically and topologically. This implies that
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}_1\oplus {\mathbb{V}}_2\,=\,{\mathbb{V}}~\,,
 $$
and the following addition map is a homeomorphism:
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}_1\times{\mathbb{V}}_2\,\longrightarrow\,{\mathbb{V}}~~,\qquad
 \left(\, v\in{{\mathbb V}}_1\,,~\,v^{\,\prime}\in{{\mathbb V}}_2\,\right)\,\longmapsto~ (v+v^{\,\prime})\in\mathbb V~~.\\~\\ 
 $$

While the extension of the above construction to a finite direct sum of TVS spaces is straightforward, splitting $\mathbb V$ into an infinite direct sum of TVS subspaces is not that trivial, especially when the number of summands is uncountable.
$$
~
$$
QUESTION

For the splitting
$$
{\mathbb V}=\bigoplus_{i\in\cal I}{\mathbb V}_i
$$
to be not only algebraic but also topological, would it be sufficient to impose the condition that the map
$$
\{{\mathbb{V}}_i\}_{i\in{\cal I}}\longrightarrow\mathbb{V}
$$
exists and is a homeomorphism?

Would this work (a) for a countable sum, and (b) for an uncountable sum (direct integral) of subspaces?

Comment: What is the topology of $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} \mathbb V_i$? What is *the map $\{\mathbb V_i\}_{i \in I}\to \mathbb V$?* Why do you write *surjective linear homeomorphism*? Homeomorphisms are always surjective and linear homeomorphisms are isomorphisms in the category of topological vector spaces (linearity of the inverse is automatic).

Comment: @Jochen Thank you. I have removed the redundant words "surjective" and "linear." Regarding your first question: I believe that the topology of $\mathbb V$ defines that of ${\mathbb V}_i$, in the induced-topology sense. I also thought that the direct sum would return the original topology of $\mathbb V$, provided $
\{{\mathbb{V}}_i\}_{i\in{\cal I}}\longrightarrow\mathbb{V}
$ is a homeomorphism. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You still did not say what *the map* is -- I don't even understand what the domain $\{\mathbb V_i\}_{i\in I}$ should be. Concerning the direct sum, there are subtle things. For example, the direct sum in the *category of topological vector spaces* of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb V_i=\mathbb R$ is not locally convex. If thus $\mathbb V$ is a locally convex spaces with an uncountable Hamel basis $I$ then *the map* (!!) $\bigoplus_{b\in I} \mathbb R\to \mathbb V$, $(\lambda_b)_{b\in I} \mapsto \sum \lambda_b b$ (which is a finite sum) is a linear bijection  but not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.

Comment: 1. What does "continuous number" mean in the title? 2. The last formula in the question is totally unclear. 3. Do you really mean here direct sum (defined via a direct limit of finite direct suns TVSs) or something else, like direct product or direct integral?

Comment: @MoisheKohan A direct integral, I would presume. I would be much in your debt if you could help me formulate my question (and that particular formula) properly. (Also, I said "uncountable", not "continuous".)

Comment: @Michael_1812 I do not think I can help since I do not understand the question. Does the following help?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_integral

Comment: And, as I said "continuous number" appears in the **title** of the question. Maybe you should edit the title to avoid this terminology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, thank you. I have corrected the title. Also, many thanks for the ref to direct integral.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What if I say that the direct sum is *countable*? Will that simplify matters?

Comment: @Michael_1812 There are many questions one can ask along these lines, but **only you** would know what interests you. Maybe if you explained the context in which this problem appears, this would help. Right now, I can only guess that you are motivated by pure curiosity (which is good!).

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Very remotely, my question is motivated by physics considerations. Usually, physicists take it for granted that the space of states in quantum field theory is Hilbert. I know, though, of at least one dissident author who suggests to consider non-Hilbert spaces. Before I start thinking his proposal over, I wish to educate myself, at a minimal level, of how general-type TVS spaces split. Hence my question: under what general condition would a general-type TVS to split into (a) a countable direct sum; (b) a direct integral of TVS subspaces?

Comment: @Jochen Could you please explain to me why this sum is a linear bijection but not a homeomorphism? Thank you!